# How to get only the hour of the system in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the current hour of the system to know if it's day or night.
I only found ways to get the current time with the date, but it's not useful for me.

Dos anyone have an idea?

Comment: If you know how to get the time, just take the hour from it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::localtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) to get the current hour by itself, eg:

```cpp
#include <ctime>

std::tm *t = std::localtime(nullptr); 
int hour = t->tm_hour;
```

Just know that getting the hour alone won't tell you whether it is day or night. You would have to look up the hour in your desired region to know that.  Different regions have different day/night times.